# How to start with bitcoin?

Tags: introducing-bitcoin

I have been listening about bitcoin from my colleagues and they convinced me to investment into bitcoin. They also suggest me couple of websites to start with. I have started with one of them and invest $150 bit seems no profit from them. Can you guys please suggest the sites or the people to with I can start my investment. Also need some guideline about how that works, sell and buy, how and when and all that primary stuff.

Answer (score 0):

One of the popular trading sites is coinbase.com. There you can sign up and buy and sell - should be straight forward. Of course there are other sites as well.